# Are there Casimir effect at the tip of a toy top to the ground?

Tags: casimir-effect

I am not a physic major rather a enthusiast and wanted to ask about the casimir effect between the tip of a top to the ground, after watching a guy spinning a top in the TV?

Certainly there may not be any such effect between a top and the air-interface (may be I am wrong) but how about the tip and the group it touches (if real)?

- It's not a specific problem, rather a curiosity. Please consider to open it.

Comment: What is "the top". The Casimir effect is a quantum effect. It's not about tops.

Comment: When you say "top," do you mean a [toy spinning top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_(toy)) or something else? Is "the group it touches" a typo for "the ground it touches"? By the way, I am confused by how you wrote "the top"; I think that maybe you meant to write "a top" instead.